# Pass the value attribute data from HTML side to JavaScript function via onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

Is there a way to pass the value attribute from HTML side to JavaScript function via onclick event?

**html/php**

```
echo '<a href="#" class="ListOfStuff" value="' . $varVal . '" onclick="doFunction(this.value)"></a>';
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    doFunction(value){
         alert(value);
    }
</script
```

this.value is undefined. This.id is the way I've handled it in the past, but now that i am dynamically writing a list with classnames, I don't quite understand how to pass the value from the HTML. This = [object OBJECT] and this.value is undefined. I can get the value if i use ID but not class.  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried writing `onClick=doFunction(event)` and then writing `alert(event.target.value);` in your Javascript?

Comment: Just tried it. `event.target = javascript:void(0);` and `event.target.value = undefined`

Comment: Okay then just write `onclick=doFunction` and `function doFunction(event) {alert(event.target.value);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the `getAttribute` method to get the value. Example:

```
<?php

$varVal = 100;
echo '<a href="#" class="ListOfStuff" value="' . $varVal . '" onclick="doFunction(this.getAttribute(\'value\'))">test</a>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doFunction(value) {
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wocik/1/edit)

Would something like this work for you? (using [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute))

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" value="myName" id="anchor" >LINK</a>
```

**JS**

```
  var a = document.getElementById("anchor");
a.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(this.getAttribute("value"));
}, false);
```